# how to use "stackedit.io" offline, ie. NOT connected to the internet, and NOT connect to a cloud?

Tags: privacy, markdown

I'm looking for a way to edit markdown documents in stackedit.io, without publishing my documents on the internet, or letting corporations spy on my personal data with facebook-like obsession.

I'm wondering if I can download the source code for stackedit.io and run it with my internet disconnected, specifically for editing markdown application locally?  Or maybe there's a similar web server application i can run local to my computer?

Comment: I think you could create an html page that loads the editor's js and be done with it.

Comment: its a good idea... its just that not really a javascript developer... i'm looking for something similar already finished... like a python script or github project i can download with said python script...

Comment: you might try to replicate stackedit with a website downloader. many come with their own web server

Comment: They are on github: https://github.com/benweet/stackedit

Comment: dependency packages are broken

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that you can run "stackedit.io" in offline mode if you install it as a "chrome app", (not to be confused with the "chrome stackedit extension" which just adds an icon that only works with cloud drives.)

I'm not sure why, but the "stackedit app" doesn't show up in the chrome webapp store but you can click this link to install it.

[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackedit/iiooodelglhkcpgbajoejffhijaclcdg/related]

or you can google for "chrome stackedit app"

once you install it, you can right click on the stackedit.io icon in chrome and select create shortcut, then it appears on your desktop like a normal desktop application.

Comment: That chrome app just opens the website...

Comment: ok, solution, number two, use Typora, markdown editor, instead [https://typora.io]

Answer (score 0):

I have solution. Check this answer in github.com:

https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/817

To leave a copy:

> Yes, there is a way.
>
> 1. You should install the extension from Chrome App Store.
> 2. You now can see in `chrome://app` StackEdit. You open it and it just loads another tab with `https://stackEdit.io/app` as URL.
> 3. At this moment, you can right-click on the icon of StackEdit in the app page, and "create direct link". You can create in desktop or in start menu. Double click on the direct link, and you get the native app of StackEdit.
> 4. Checking the direct link created, you will see the destination is:
>
> ```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --profile-directory=Default --app-id=olheigmnhdlofgjiponfkcnofipcljko
> ```
>
> Create a link like this, will also do. Enjoy!
>
> Alternatively, at step 2, on the StackEdit.io webpage, you can click the "three dots" Chrome menu, and choose "Open in StackEdit". This will also create a dedicated window of app.
>
> But, I have the sense of that the author just doesn't want us to use it like this? But it is good and pretty as a native app, at least in my Windows 10. Maybe because chrome extension as App is deprecated by Chrome. Can the author explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You can put an icon on your desktop.  It doesn't really address your request as it just loads the app against the website like the other solutions, but it's a little better.

Assuming you've installed the app in Chrome (there's both an app and an extension), go to the apps panel with the `chrome://apps/` url.  You should be able to find a big tile with the stackedit icon.  You can right-click this icon and there's an option to "create shortcuts".  Under that there are two options: one will put an icon on the desktop, the other will "pin to taskbar".

According to the app page in the Chrome store,

> Documents are stored in the browser's local storage, which means they are not shared between different browsers/computers. Furthermore, clearing your browser's data may delete all your local documents.

I think that means it works offline, and you'd have to "publish" it to somewhere to store it.